# Element differences of tensor with each other along spatial axises (Pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I want to get the difference of a channel to all other channels along the spatial axes (1, 2). The lengths of c_deltas and c_in should be equal.

```
in_shape = [bs, y_dim, x_dim, c_in]
out_shape = [bs, y_dim, x_dim, c_in, c_deltas]
```

Here are some examples (1d and 4d) with the expected results:

```
# 1d example; in.size=(4), out.size=(4, 4)
in_matrix = [1, 3, 4, 7]
out_matrix = [[0, 2, 3, 6], [-2, 0, 1, 4], [-3, -1, 0, 3], [-6, -4, -1, 0]]

# 4d example; in.size=(1, 2, 2, 3), out.size=(1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
in_matrix=[[[[6,5,1], [2, 5, 3]], [[1, 4, 8], [8, 6, 4]]]]
out_matrix =  [[[[[0, -1, -5], [1, 0, -4], [5, 4, 0]],
                 [[0, 3, 1], [-3, 0, -2], [-1, 2, 0]]],
                [[[0, 3, 7], [-3, 0, 4], [-7, -4, 0]],
                 [[0, -2, -4], [2, 0, -2], [4, 2, 0]]]]]
```

I was able to find *some* similar questions; however, I was unable to cleanly generalize them for my use e.g., https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/compute-difference-of-each-element-in-a-tensor-with-each-other/44087/2

Is there an efficient way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an [outer operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product), given a single tensor shaped `(*, i)`, you are looking to compute an operation cross-element-wise resulting in a tensor shaped `(*,i,i)`. You can achieve this by thoughtfully unsqueezing extra dimensions on the initial tensor.

In your first example, you have a shape of `(i,)`, if you unsqueeze dimensions twice two different ways: one as `(i,1)` and the other `(1,i)`, then applying an element-wise operator (such as `__sub__`, `__add__`, etc...) between the two will perform the outer operation: the result will be shaped `(i,i)`.

In your case:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([1, 3, 4, 7])
>>> x[None]-x[:,None]
tensor([[ 0,  2,  3,  6],
        [-2,  0,  1,  4],
        [-3, -1,  0,  3],
        [-6, -4, -3,  0]])
```

You always need to unsqueeze around the dimension of interest, *ie.* on the last and before-last dimensions. So in the 4D case:

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[[[6,5,1], [2, 5, 3]], [[1, 4, 8], [8, 6, 4]]]])
>>> x[...,None,:]-x[...,None]
tensor([[[[[ 0, -1, -5],
           [ 1,  0, -4],
           [ 5,  4,  0]],

          [[ 0,  3,  1],
           [-3,  0, -2],
           [-1,  2,  0]]],


         [[[ 0,  3,  7],
           [-3,  0,  4],
           [-7, -4,  0]],

          [[ 0, -2, -4],
           [ 2,  0, -2],
           [ 4,  2,  0]]]]])
```